# Android emulator just displaying google map logo instead of map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

android emulator just displaying google map logo instead of map using react native.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share a fully-reproducible, minimal demo.

Comment: Provides more info relating to this. Like exact code segments